# Javascript spreading an object's properties array at specific index

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Given a react hook and an object with array properties, I want to find a way to update the hook by using the spread operator at a specific properties index. Here is an example where I want to take the index `0` of the array in each property and spread it

```js
const [{ a, b, c }, setState] = useState({ a : 'x', b : 'x', c : 'y' })

const temp = {
    a : ['x1', 'y1'],
    b : ['x2', 'y2'],
    c : ['x3', 'y3']
}

setState({...temp[0]})

/* Expected to be spread onto
*  setState({
*    a : 'x1',
*    b : 'x2',
*    c : 'x3'
*  })
*/
```

How would I achieve this? Am I looking at the wrong place to begin with by using the spread operator?

#### Things I have tried

- Tried looking into `.filter()` but I was not able to make it work
- Tried playing around with the `[0]` position and other syntaxes but with no success either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map over [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and then convert the result to an object with [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

```js
const temp = {
    a : ['x1', 'y1'],
    b : ['x2', 'y2'],
    c : ['x3', 'y3']
}
let res = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(temp).map(([k,[v]])=>[k, v]));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```js
const temp = {
    a : ['x1', 'y1'],
    b : ['x2', 'y2'],
    c : ['x3', 'y3']
};

let obj = {};
Object.keys(temp).forEach(k=> obj[k] = temp[k][0]);

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to use the spread operator to do what you want, but you can accomplish this with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), something like

```
const temp = {
    a : ['x1', 'y1'],
    b : ['x2', 'y2'],
    c : ['x3', 'y3']
};

const indexToGrab = 0;

const newState = Object.entries(temp).reduce((acc, currentEntry) => {
    acc[currentEntry[0]] = currentEntry[1][indexToGrab];
    return acc;
}, {});
//{a: 'x1', b: 'x2', c: 'x3'}

setState(newState);
```